# How to deserialize array using Dapper

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, dapper

I have a model that has a `HashSet<int>` member. Since I wasn't able to get Dapper to automatically create the set from an array, I thought I would just use a multi-mapping query and get the array as a separate column, split on it and create the set inside a lambda. Just to be clear, I want to deserialize the whole model, not just the bit for the set.

My first multi-mapping attempt also failed, so I decided to try something simpler, get an array and deserialize it into a `List<int>` or `int[]`. And this is where I'm stuck.

I am using a PostgreSQL 12 database.

Code snippet is as follows

```
var query = "SELECT ARRAY[1, 2, 3];";

var ints1 = await _conn.QueryAsync<List<int>>(query); // This returns an empty array
var ints2 = await _conn.QueryAsync<int[]>(query); // System.ArgumentException: Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod.
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong and Google doesn't really seem to help, I only find questions about using lists in queries.

Edit: Ok, I got it working by converting the array into a JSON, but I still find this solution ugly. Is there a way to avoid creating JSONs?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on SQL but `SELECT ARRAY[1, 2, 3]` does not seem to be common SQL, postgres or no? I'd probably suggest that Dapper possibly just doesn't support this pretty funky syntax

Comment: I'm not familiar with postgres, does `query` return 3 rows of one column? One row of 3 columns? Or one row, once column?

Comment: @Crowcoder It returns a single row with the value `{1, 2, 3}`

Comment: As a string? Well how would you expect Dapper to magically know that is a list of ints?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think Dapper deserializes that way. It expects more standard sql result sets.

Comment: @Xzenon what was the issue with your multi-mapping solution and the separate column?

Comment: @johnmoarr I was trying to get the other column as a list and it would be empty.

Comment: @Liam The following query `SELECT pg_typeof(ARRAY[1,2,3])` returns "integer[]", so I was expecting Dapper to somehow know that is not a string. Also, getting the result as a string throws an exception.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't. Dapper is just a wrapper for ADO.Net. Why are you trying to get SQL to just return 1,2,3? None of this really makes any sense

Comment: @Liam I have a column in my actual table that contains an array of ints. It's not 1,2,3, but it's the same data type. It was just easier for me to try and debug a really dumbed down version of the code.

Comment: @Xzenon if you had a separate column with all the int values, you could just query (only) this column with `var myVals = (await _conn.QueryAsync<int>(query)).ToList()` and you will be retrieving a list.

Comment: @johnmoarr I'm trying to deserialize the whole model, the array column was just the bit that I was having trouble with.

Comment: *I have a column in my actual table that contains an array of ints* ok, well what data type is that column? It seems like your mixing up two things, getting the raw data out of SQL and processing that data. Dapper doesn't process data. It reads it raw. If it's for example a varchar then you should read that as a string in Dapper then process that string using whatever format you've specified

Comment: @Liam The type in the database is _int4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't believe everything you hear, although its stated above that its not possible it's actually easily achieveable.

It's true that the query below will give you an error: (Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod):

```
var arrayOfThreeElements =  
        (await _conn.QueryAsync<int[]>("SELECT ARRAY[1, 2, 3]"))                  
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

What you need to do is to tell dapper how to handle this using a small TypeHandler:

```
public class GenericArrayHandler<T> : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<T[]>
{
    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, T[] value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }

    public override T[] Parse(object value) => (T[]) value;
}
```

The Parse method is the important one here.

Then you just add this handler where you have added all your other typehandlers - i.e in the Initialization code of your app or website like this:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new GenericArrayHandler<int>());
```

Now the query works and returns the 3 elements, 1,2 and 3 in an integer array.

Comment: You could probably just do this with a Generic typehandler as well. I.e. GenericArrayHandler<T> : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<T[]> - and add new GenericArrayHandler<int>(). Then the goal could easily be achieved for any array type encountered.

Comment: I tested it with a GenericArrayHandler as mentioned, and it is indeed just as good. Which makes it extremely easy to use array columns for any type.

Comment: I changed the answer to use a GenericArrayHandler instead to accomodate other types than int

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comments, but TL;DR this can't be done. The array has to be converted to a string and then deserialized into the list.

I'm answering this question instead of closing it, since I believe it's a valid question if you've mostly used Postgres and maybe expect arrays to be a thing in other RDMSs.

Comment: There's an answer above. If it works, please mark it as accepted, or comment if it is not.