# How to convert a database column into List<string> before setting it's model type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am not sure if I used the correct terms in my question but my problem is this:

In my table `unit_properties`, I have a column named `images`,

I also have a model

```
public class UnitProperty
{
    public long? UnitId { get; set; }
    public string? UnitTitle { get; set; }
    public string? UnitDescription { get; set; }
    public string? UnitImages { get; set; } //point-a
    public string? UnitAddress { get; set; }
    public int? UnitRooms { get; set; }
    public int? UnitBathrooms { get; set; }
    public int? UnitSquareMeters { get; set; }
    public bool? UnitHasParking { get; set; }
    public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int? UnitWalkScore { get; set; }
    public int? UnitTransitScore { get; set; }
    public int? UnitBikeScore { get; set; }
    public User? Agent { get; set; }
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is working as expected until I changed point-a to this `public List<string>? UnitImages { get; set; }`

since my table `unit_properties.images` has a string value of `["a","b","c","d"]`, I want it to return  a structure like this one:

```
[
  {
    "unitId": 1,
    "unitTitle": "1 Bedroom Studio",
    "unitDescription": "Fully renovated and move in ready apartments are available for rent...",
    "unitImages": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
       ],
    "unitAddress": "6876 86 Street Edmonton",
    "unitRooms": 1,
```

Here is the complete code that works with `public string unitImages {get;set;}`

```
// GET: api/<UnitPropertyController>
[HttpGet("Units", Name = "GetUnits")]
public async Task<List<UnitProperty>> GetUnitsAsync([FromServices] MySqlConnection connection)
{
    string query = @"
    SELECT
        up.id as unitId,
        up.title as unitTitle,
        up.description as unitDescription,
        up.images as unitImages,
        up.address as unitAddress,
        up.rooms as unitRooms,
        up.bathrooms as unitBathrooms,
        up.square_meters as unitSquareMeters,
        up.has_parking as unitHasParking,
        up.price as unitPrice,
        up.walk_score as unitWalkScore,
        up.transit_score as unitTransitScore,
        up.bike_score as unitBikeScore,
        up.agent_id,
        up.category_id,

        c.id as categoryId,
        c.name as categoryName,
        c.image as categoryImage,

        u.id as userId,
        u.name as userName,
        u.image as userImage,
        u.email as userEmail,
        u.phone_number as userPhoneNumber,
        u.address as userAddress,
        u.description as userDescription,
        u.user_role as userRole

    FROM unit_properties up
    INNER JOIN categories c ON up.category_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN users u ON up.agent_id = u.id;
";

var multiQuery = await connection.QueryMultipleAsync(query);
var unitProperties = multiQuery.Read<UnitProperty, Category, User, UnitProperty>(
    (unitProperty, category, user) =>
    {
        unitProperty.Category = category;
        unitProperty.Agent = user;

        return unitProperty;
    },
    splitOn: "categoryId,userId"
);

List<UnitProperty> results = unitProperties.ToList();

return results;

}
```

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915756/how-to-deserialize-array-using-dapper

Comment: already tried it but it doesnt work, db column unit_properties.images is a type string.

Comment: then the type of db column should've been mentioned in the question, as e.g. PostgreSQL allow for array column type, so there is an ambiguity

Comment: Why you don't store these UnitImages in a separate table? It seems your table is not normalized correctly, this gives you a maintenance nightmare. Then you could also use the multi mapping feature from dapper. https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree, I am maintaining this project from another developer.